# Force Change System Clock without Reset to Correct Time

Tags: time, system, clock

I'm trying to change the system clock to another random value in order to check something out, but at the strike of the next minute the clock resets back to the correct time. Any ideas?

Comment: More details about your system?  This doesn't happen for me.

Comment: Is `ntpd` running?

Comment: you didn't even mention about your system/platform. Mac/Win/Linux/iOS/Android?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.